# Qt-5.8 on CentOS 7

Tags: qt, centos7, qt5.8

I have installed Qt from source on site: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/8.0/x/qt5.html
and followed instructions below.
Now I have 4 icons for Qt5 Assistant, Qt5 Designer, Qt5 Linguist, Qt5 QDbusViewer BUT no any text inside this programs. Just "___" instead. 
How to reduce this problem?

[image: screenshot(no any text)]

I need to run progect created on Windows in Qt-5.8 on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be some fonts missing. Take a look at [this question](https://forum.qt.io/topic/74357/no-text-in-compiled-application/3) from the Qt forums.

Comment: @Darya, could you solve the problem? I've seen this issue too in several MS Windows installations and fonts were the reasons.